# Isn't Google Guice just another Factory?

Tags: java, design-patterns, guice

I want to instantiate an User Account. I can use a factory such as this:

```
public class UserFactory {
  public User newUser(UserType type) {
    if (type == UserType.FREE) return new FreeUser();
  }
}

User user = UserFactory.newUser(UserType.FREE);  //UserType.FREE is an enum
```

Now if I use Google Guice, I must write a "module":

```
public class UserModule extends AbstractModule {

  public voidSetType(UserType type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  @Override 
  protected void configure() {
    if (this.type = UserType.FREE)
      bind(User.class).to(FreeUser.class);
    else bind .....
  }
}
```

Then, this is client code:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new UserModule().setType(UserType.FREE)));
```

My question is:
Instead of writing a factory class, I have to write a module class. And from the example above, I don't see any advantage.
The Module class use reflection, it's slower than my assignment statement in the factory class.
The Module class is not any simpler than the factory class. Instead of maintaining the factory, I must maintain the module.

What is the real advantage anyway? Isn't Google Guice just another factory class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not seeing an advantage as Guice ([Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)) is not designed to replace [factories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern). It can do to a limited degree (see AssistedInject and Providers) but if you have logic in your factory then it is unlikely that you will be able to use Guice as a direct replacement.

The Guice way for this would be to still have a factory and Guice would inject the factory. Now User sounds like a domain object, and most likely not require a Guice injected dependency tree. If it does then the factory should be Guice aware and either take `Provider`s for each User types or have direct access to the Inject to create User objects using different [`Key`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Key.html)s.

DI is all about dependency trees. Factories are all about producing objects without the caller having to care about how that object is implemented. They have cross over and can be used together, but they are addressing different problems.

Answer (score 2):

Guice is decidedly NOT just a factory.  It is intended to reduce the boilerplate of construction of collaborators in the system, and to separate the responsibility for creating the dependencies of those collaborators out.  The reasons for this include:

1. Reduced boilerplate code (if you do it right)
2. Dependencies are abstracted, and so can be swapped in at:

   - test time - fake/mock/stub implementations can be swapped in
   - run time - alternate implementations can be swapped in when features change.
3. Design principle considerations such as "Interface Segregation" and "Single Responsibility"

As another answer said, there is crossover between dependency-injection and factories - they both involve objects being managed and having their dependencies satisfied by an external system, but they work differently.  In this case, you would want the factory.  But with Dependency-Injection, if you have lots of factories which require each other to work properly, you can have a dependency-injection framework like Guice manage the interdependence of factories without a lot of manual wiring code and other boilerplate.

I tend to like to break down what dependencies exist into a few different types, and consider injection only for some types.

```
+======================+=============================+====================+
| Type                 | Note                        | Inject?            |
+======================+=============================+====================+
| Static Dependencies  | Inherited types             | N/A                |
+----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| Collaborators        | Services, Factories, etc.   | Definitely         |
+----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| Configuration        | Context                     | Maybe - be careful |
+----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| Consumables/Data     | Value types                 | No - use factories |
+======================+=============================+====================+
```

Of course, no rules are hard and fast, but generally speaking, I try to not inject value types, unless they're being used immutably as context for the entire scope of the dependent objects.

So, using a User type as a context, say, for a request is fine, but only if it's immutable and provided as "global context" for all objects whose scope is that request.  But if I'm intending to operate on that User, I will manage it with factories, probably in another separate workflow/request.

Automated dependency injection is great for managing collaborators, services, utility classes - the big pieces of your app.  You can, of course, bring it down to the micro level, but you need to be quite careful to not go too crazy with that, or to be aware of the trade-offs in complexity.  Yes, your code will get more generic and more reusable and abstract - but also effects will have less obvious causes (an error now can be the result of initialization far earlier in the running system), your flow will be less linear, and your code can seem more magical.

If you find yourself writing way more module code than you are saving from manual wiring, then re-consider your design.

Side notes:
1. You can derive Guice and Dependency-Injection frameworks by refactoring factories and wiring code to the extreme, but factories are specifically purposed to manage particular classes - Guice is generic by definition, so isn't suited to replace some kinds of factories.  Pure-boilerplate factories, perhaps.
2. You can inject value types using injection, but you run into difficulties - value types (domain objects) can require dependency cycles legitimately, which Guice and others aren't really intended for, though they support it.  You are playing with fire, but in a system where everyone understands the style and approach, it can be powerful.  Use with extreme caution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need "UserType"?

consider this:

```
class FreeUser extends User {...}
class NonFreeUser extends User {...}

void configure() {
  // if Type=Free
  bind(User.class).annotatedWith(Free.class).to(FreeUser.class);
  // else
  bind(User.class).to(NonFreeUser.class)
}
```

and then

```
class SomeClassThatNeedsAFreeUser {
   @Inject
   @Free
   private User user;

}
```

so when you use injector.getInstance(SomeClassThatNeedsAFreeUser.class), you will get an Instance that automatically has a FreeSUer injected ... I think this is a far better approach than tight coupling via specific factories.

Comment: Pseudo-Code by hand, will not compile unless you fix the missing parts

Comment: I need UserType because I want users to choose which type of account they want to sign up. If they choose Free then the browser will send "Free" parameter, it's a string, it's not type safe, so I will convert it to enum.